# TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I am doing up a log-in page but I'm unsure why the validation script is not loading. I was able to log in without an error like this yesterday. However, when I tried to log in today, I was met with this error.

Is it the placement of my script?

I've tried rearranging the scripts, and checking other files such as my js and the file location of jquery.validate.min.js, but all seems fine.

.html

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<!--<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">-->
<!--<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="../Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="lib/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<!--<link href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />-->

<script src="scripts/common.js"></script>
```

.JS

```
var userid;
var password;

 $(document).ready (function () {

    $("#LoginForm").validate({   // this line is the error highlighted in console
        messages: {
            txtLogin: "User ID is required",
            txtPassword: "Password is required",
        },
```

I believe I should be able to log in after solving this as I have configured my PHP and other files correctly. The JS file seems fine too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use the `validation` method of `jQuery`, you need to import the relative plugin:

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

Also, at start of your JavaScript file insert this:

```
require('jquery-validation');
```

For example:

```
<form>
    <input required>
</form>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script>
    $("form").validate();
</script>
```

See the [official documentation](https://github.com/jquery-validation/jquery-validation) for more information.

Comment: Hello! I've tried to insert require('jquery-validation'); at the start of my JS file, but i'm caught with an error that require is not defined. Do you have knowledge on that? Thank you.

Comment: @matthew did you put `require('jquery-validation');` after the jQuery include?

Comment: yes i did, right at the top. my javascript file starts with (function () {
    "use strict"; and i've put it on top of that on line 1, but that's causing a reference error too